# How to avoid adapting to zooming in responsive design?

Tags: responsive-design

I’m not english speaker and I will try to explain my problem in the better way I can.

I’m designing my first responsive website using CSS.
Until now the things are going slow but fine.

My first test page is responding correctly in all widths of the desktop browsers, including narrowing them until its smaller width.
After this tests I loaded the page in my NOKIA 5800 smartphone that uses Symbian.

My main problem is the following:

The test page is loaded correctly in NOKIA 5800 smartphone and when I rotate the phone, the page adapts it internal elements to the new width.

It is OK, BUT… when I zoom the page (double clicking on the screen), the page is zoomed and the browser narrows AGAIN the internal elements to the new more narrow width and I dont want the page be responsive in zoom (FOR EXAMPLE: when the page is loaded at 320px width resolution)
I want the elements only be zoomed when I zoom the page. Am I explaining correctly?
My page appears to be so much responsive!!!!! :) or some thing is not working fine.

In other words…. even the page adapts the DIVs (etc) at the more narrow width on desktop browsers, the problem is when I zoom in smaller screens (smartphone), because some elements are additionally narrowed and it is so much .

I used several variations of tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

... but this kind of smartphone stills adapting the widths when zooming the page.
Some thing is not working.

I limited the body to `zoom: 1` in the CSS
Body width is set in 100% for all resolutions.

I need that when zooming (scaling) the page, these widths dont be modified.

Before destroying my smartphone :) I ask…

**Is there some way in CSS to avoid the responsive effect when I zoom?**

I don't know what more I can do.

I hope I have explained this issue clearly so that someone can help me.

---

These are the main parts of the CSSs

## in Main CSS:

```
body {
    /*background-color: white;*/
    background-image: url('images/background_pages_gris-ruido.jpg');
    line-height: normal;
    color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    zoom: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

## In MEDIA Css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1152px){
body {
    background-color: transparent;
line-height: normal;
}
#DIV_GLOBAL {
    width: auto;/*950px;*/;
    display: table;
    float: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
}
```

Now I revised the test page using an iPad and a Samsung Galaxy S3 smartphone. In these devices the page can not be zoomed.

The problem is with smartphones like my Nokia 5800. Is there some way to avoid responsive effect when zoom?

I hope these data can be enough to analize. Thank you! GusSiglo21

Comment: Could you maybe show us the CSS code which you used to make the relevant elements responsive?

Comment: Does it work the same way on other phones and tablets? Symbian browsers have some unique features.